# QMap to and from a textual representation - QTextStream?

Tags: c++, passwords, qt, macos

I am working on some code (part of KDE's kwallet) that stores a QMap as a binary representation, using

```
QByteArray mapData;
QDataStream ds(&mapData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
ds << map;
```

Elsewhere, such binary representations are read back into a QMap using

```
QByteArray v;
if( !v.isEmpty() ){
    QDataStream ds( &v, QIODevice::ReadOnly );
    ds >> map;
}
```

I'd like to modify this so that a text representation is used. I came across a suggestion on a Qt forum that one could use a QTextStream instead of QDataStream. No example solution was given, and when I simply replace the latter by the former function in my code, it won't compile as QMap lacks the corresponding << and >> operators.
Am I missing something, or is what I want simply impossible without writing my own parser (for reading back the stored data)?

Comment: The << and >> operators are syntactical sugar. The fact that they do not work with a text stream is an indication that the code is probably not there to support reading and writing as text to begin with. Unfortunately I am not a Qt expert and cannot provide a quality answer to your question, but I would first make sure it cannot be done out of the box then write a pair of standalone functions to do this if the functionality is not already there.

Comment: The QMap << and >> operators work with QDataStream, but if you do

    qWarning() << map

you get a very nicely formatted and human readable output on the terminal. So somewhere there's code that does the conversion *to* a text stream.

For now, I've worked around the underlying issue by storing not mapData but mapData.toBase64(). That way I at least get a textual representation with only printable characters.

Comment: My point is `operator<<()` might be defined for a data stream but not a text stream. Overloaded functions are different functions.

Comment: All Qt classes used to be able to serialize to/from a text stream in addition to the datastream, that functionality was removed somewhere around 4.3 or so iirc. you might be able to find some of the old code going back a few versions. I also don't remember if you just switched the streams or if it was a configuration on the datastream.